# Solving problem of limit

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^3\left(\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^4}}-x\sqrt2\right)$$

*I tried to solve it in this way*

- I rationalize the second part and I get

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^3\frac{\sqrt{1+x^4}-x\sqrt2}{\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^4}}+x\sqrt2} $$

- Then I rationalize the upper part again and get

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^3\frac{\sqrt{1+x^4}+x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^4}}-x\sqrt 2}$$

- Then I took common $x$ from the lower first part and $x^2$ from the lower second part and cut the upper and lower $x^3$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^4}+1}+1}{\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+1^4}}+\sqrt 2\right)}$$

- Then I put $x= \infty$ then I got

$$\frac 1{2(2+\sqrt 2)}$$ 
But the answer is $$\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}$$
What did I do wrong?

Comment: It's unreadable as-is, looks like the answer is $+\infty$

Comment: I've attempted to format with MathJax. Not entirely convinced I've written everything correctly though

Comment: @lioness99a Thank you so much.  And its totally correct

Comment: @MCCCS I'm really sorry.I don't know how to use that.

Comment: @user7843617 No worries, and MCCCS gave you the link so that you can learn how to use LaTeX formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of your work should be
$$x^3\frac{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^4}-2x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^4}}+x\sqrt2}
=x^3\frac{\sqrt{1+x^4}-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^4}}+x\sqrt2}$$
which is equal to
$$\frac{x^3}{(\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^4}}+x\sqrt2)(\sqrt{1+x^4}+x^2)}$$
Now as $x\to +\infty$ we get
$$\frac{1}{(\sqrt{1+1}+\sqrt2)(1+1)}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}.$$

This is another approach
\begin{align*}x^3\left(\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^4}}-x\sqrt{2}\right)&=
x^4\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+1/x^4}}-\sqrt{2}\right)\\
&=x^4\left(\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{2x^4}+o(1/x^4)}-\sqrt{2}\right)\\
&=x^4\sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4x^4}+o(1/x^4)}-1\right)\\
&=x^4\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{1}{8x^4}+o(1/x^4)\right)\to\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}.
\end{align*}
where we used the fact that $\sqrt{1+t}=1+\frac{t}{2}+o(t)$ as $t\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm such a duffer. I exactly did like your first method but I did the last step wrong. Your last approach is awesome. I couldn't think of that way.